# scheduleLocalNotification does not invoke didReceiveLocalNotification

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I am using `UILocalNotification`

The problem is when I use `scheduleLocalNotification` to post my notification , it never triggers `didReceiveLocalNotification` while `presentLocalNotificationNow` does it everytime.

I need to show an alert in didReceiveLocalNotification but with scheduleLocalNotification and not presentLocalNotificationNow.

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

From the Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide:

> In iOS 8 and later, apps that use either local or remote notifications
>   must register the types of notifications they intend to deliver. The
>   system then gives the user the ability to limit the types of
>   notifications your app displays. The system does not badge icons,
>   display alert messages, or play alert sounds if any of these
>   notification types are not enabled for your app, even if they are
>   specified in the notification payload.

As shown in the guide, the sample code that Apple shows is:

```
UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
         UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
```

UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =
            [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];